# Is it possible to rename tabs in safari?

Tags: safari, software-recommendation, tabs

In the Safari app on Mac (Ventura 13), it is possible to rename *tab groups* by going to the sidebar and control-clicking on the name of the tab group. However, it possible to rename the *tabs themselves*, possibly with the use of third-party software? Right now, it is sometimes difficult to see what the name of a tab refers to, and so it would be useful to be able to customise this.

Comment: I know a way to rename a pinned tab if that can help you. You tell me

Comment: @Thinkr: Yes, it would be very helpful if you could share your method. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I've posted it as an answer. ;)

Comment: @Thinkr: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be the best workaround given that one cannot directly rename tabs in Safari.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [asked in the comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460228/is-it-possible-to-rename-tabs-in-safari/460267#comment675042_460228), here is how to rename a pinned tab.

---

Once you're on the page you want to rename (currently unpinned), [add the page to your favorites](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/see-your-favorite-websites-sfri22092/mac) by hovering over the Smart Search field, clicking on the "+" button and choosing to add it to your favorites; when you add it, you'll have the option to rename it: rename it as you wish.

Now open the page you've just saved in a new tab and [pin it](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/ibrw0495694f/mac). You should see the new name.

---

I've just tried it on iPad and iPhone and it doesn't work there, it only works on Mac.